How to use C++ shared libraries with Bazel
I have following issue. I have two shared libs (using cc_binary) and one executable.
If I run main, I'd expect to show same values in printvs independent from where I call it. But I get, a 0 when calling from main. I don't understand why, because the vs() symbols should be located in lib1.so, which should be shared to every consumer. Could someone explain what's wrong?
lib1.h
#pragma once
#include <vector>

struct Services
{
    static std::vector<int> &vs();
    static void printvs();
};

lib1.cc
#include "lib1.h"

#include <iostream>

std::vector<int>& Services::vs()
{
    static std::vector<int> v;
    return v;
}

void Services::printvs()
{
    std::cout << Services::vs().size() << std::endl;
}

lib2.cc
#include "lib1.h"

static bool init()
{
    Services::vs().push_back(1);
    Services::vs().push_back(2);
    Services::printvs();
    return true;
}

[[maybe_unused]] bool i = init();

main.cc
#include "lib1.h"
int main()
{
    Services::printvs();
}

BUILD.bazel
cc_library(
    name = "lib1_lib",
    srcs = ["lib1.cc"],
    hdrs = ["lib1.h"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "lib1",
    srcs = ["lib1_lib"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    linkshared = 1,
)

cc_library(
    name = "lib2_lib",
    srcs = ["lib2.cc"],
    deps = ["lib1_lib"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "lib2",
    srcs = ["lib2_lib"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    linkshared = 1,
)

cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cc", ":lib2", ":lib1"],
    deps = [":lib1_lib"],
)


that's how static linking works, this has nothing to do with linux, you would get the same behavior on windows or MacOs.

All three binaries have their own copy of lib1_lib and therefore aren't sharing variables. Why not just link to lib1 instead?

I already link to lib1. That' how Bazel works. It takes the src and links against it. the deps hold the compiere dep to be able to include the lib.h from main.

It isn't clear what output you are getting and what you expect instead.

i exptect 22 I get 20

Hard to tell what's going on. My distro doesn't pack bazel and I don't feel like downoading it. Normal manual build produces what you expect. Perhaps try to capture the commands that bazel runs and show them in the question.

I don't know bazel either but it does seem like changing deps = ["lib1_lib"] to deps = ["lib1"] would fix the problem

@SteffenRoeber "i exptect 22 I get 20" -- Maybe your question should claim this instead of "I get, a 0". Sure, technically, you do get a 0 (and a 2) as part of getting 20, but phrasing the result like the question does is rather confusing/misleading.

Please [edit] your question to include expected and actual output. Comments here are not the right place for important information.

You're linking lib1.cc into the binary multiple times, which is generally a bad idea for reasons like you encountered. Use cc_shared_library instead, which checks for this and tells you.
cc_library(
    name = "lib1_lib",
    srcs = ["lib1.cc"],
    hdrs = ["lib1.h"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_shared_library(
    name = "lib1",
    deps = ["lib1_lib"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "lib2_lib",
    srcs = ["lib2.cc"],
    deps = ["lib1_lib"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_shared_library(
    name = "lib2",
    deps = ["lib2_lib"],
    dynamic_deps = ["lib2"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cc"],
    deps = [":lib1_lib"],
    dynamic_deps = ["lib1", "lib2"],
)

Note the redundant lib2 in dynamic_deps for main. See bazelbuild/bazel#21819 for why that's necessary.

Yes I tried that before and it worked. But what's then the diff to cc_binary, which also creates a. so

cc_binary exposes the output as a single file. cc_shared_library aggregates information about all of the transitive dependencies for rules which depend on it to make use of. In particular, it keeps track of all the cc_library rules which have already been linked and avoids linking them again.
